# Using Font Awesome icons in Mailchimp campaign

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-awesome, mailchimp

I have created an HTML template for a mailchimp campaign that includes font awesome icons in the footer. If I send the HTML email using Mandrill, its works fine. When I import the HTML into a Mailchimp template, the icons dont appear.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
.footer i {
        color: #999;
        margin: 0 2px;
    }

    .footer i:hover {
        color: #333;
    }

    .footer p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .footer a i {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

Here are the icons in use:

```
<p>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>
  <a href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
  <a href="http://pinterest.com/"><i class="fa fa-pinterest fa-2x"></i>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use inline CSS as it says :

> Use inline CSS Because browser-based email applications, such as
>   Gmail, strip out `<head>` and `<body>` tags by default, always use
>   inline CSS over embedded CSS.

Read the [link](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/ways-to-build/css-in-html-email)

Try converting your code [here](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) and then mail it

Comment: Sorry, but font icons won't work on e-mail clients. This won't fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this. Unfortunately e-mail clients are way too limited. Most can't handle any CSS3, nor @font-face (that's what font-awesome uses for the icons). If you want Outlook support - you certainly want - you shouldn't use the icons as background images too.

The only safe way is to convert every icon to images. Fortunately, [iconmoon](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) can help. Choose the icons you need, select to download as SVG/PNG and use the PNG files.

**Another warning**: use tables for layout, like you were in 1998, no floats or fancy stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking: "How can I use a HTML template, which includes Font Awesome icons, in a MailChimp campaign?" then I can't help.

But I can answer "How can I use Font Awesome icons in a MailChimp campaign?"

The only way that I found that works is to build your MailChimp campaign on their website, using their campaign editor/designer. Basically, I had to turn the icon into an image, and in-line and re-size it to fit my needs. Extra manual work, but this is what I needed. Hope this helps.